# Woocommerce add to cart button redirect to checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created an ecommerce using the plugin woocommerce. I am selling only a subscription so the "/cart/" page is useless. I'm trying to get rid of it so that when my customer click on "Add to cart" button, he ends up on the checkout page.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In WooCommerce 3.6 or later you can use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` (props @roman)

```php
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function( $url, $adding_to_cart ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}, 10, 2 );
```

---

Original answer:

you can use a filter in functions.php:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

it doesn't seem to work with ajax, but it works from the single product pages, which I think is what you use

On WooCommerce (>= 2.1) the function can be simplified as:

```
function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
}
```

Comment: You are my official new best friend. 

TYVM

Comment: Hi Guys, How can i add that functionality for a specific products category ?

Comment: @RoeeYossef one way can be to alter the add-to-cart link adding something like : add_query_arg( array( 'direct-checkout-redirect' => 1 ), $_product->add_to_cart_url() ); and then into function redirect_to_checkout(), checking for "direct-checkout-redirect" param.

Comment: Caveat - if you turn off Ajax in Settings->Product->Display, the second example still stops in the checkout line. The first example, however, behaves even from a direct link.= ( ?add-to-cart=[PRODUCT-ID]&variation_id=[VARIATION-ID]&attribute_[ATTRIBUTE-NAME]=[ATTRIBUTE-SLUG]&attribute_[ATTRIBUTE-NAME]=[ATTRIBUTE-SLUG] )

Comment: The first code was strangely adding a different product only on mobile, second code fixed this.

Comment: get_checkout_url() is deprecated as of 2.5.0 in favor to wc_get_checkout_url()

Comment: The "add_to_cart_redirect" hook uses out of date data structures and is <strong>deprecated</strong> since WooCommerce version 3.1.1! Use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect instead.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for specific items?

Comment: From Woocommerce 2.5 (the former function) and from 3.0 (the hook) are deprecated. This should work for everyone running 3.0 or later:

`add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout() {
 return wc_get_checkout_url();
}`

Answer (score 14):

There is an option within WooCommerce settings that allows you to enable this functionality:

[image: Option to redirect visitor to cart page]

Simply login to your WP admin panel > WooCommerce > Catalog and select the option. I hope this helps!

Comment: On seconds read it looks like you want to skip the cart page and redirect to the checkout...

Comment: Exactly, I'm using at the moment this option. But like you just said I'd like to get straight to the checkout.

Comment: @DevinWalker what if you need to redirect only with few condition and continue to use ajax in the other case?

Answer (score 14):

I've found a simple solution that work like magic.

1. As mentioned by @Ewout, check the box that says "Redirecto to cart page after succesful addtion".
2. Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout (Tab) - where you should select pages for cart and checkout, select the checkout page as the cart page (image attached).

That's it. works for me.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this is new a new feature of woocomerce because that option wasn't there when I asked the question. I haven't tested it but +1 for the update.

Comment: Don't do this - when Woocommerce detects someone visiting the checkout page with an empty cart, it will try and redirect them to the cart page. Because these are one and the same, it will end up in an endless redirect loop.

Comment: I have the latest version and they have moved all these functions.  Can't find redirect anywhere in ui :(

Comment: I don't understand what Lewis meant. I have followed the instructions above. Then, I went to mydomain.com/checkout/ and I had an expected empty checkout page.

Answer (score 6):

### Update for WooCommerce 3.5.1

Step 1.
First of all go to WooCommerce Products settings and deactivate AJAX add to cart.

Step 2. 
Use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` hook to make a redirect to checkout.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
});
```

Of course there some small things are left to do, like changing add to cart buttons text and removing some WooCommerce cart-related notices. I recommend to check this tutorial for more https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/redirect-to-checkout-skip-cart.html

Answer (score 3):

@RemiCorson posted this brief but beneficial tutorial:

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-skip-product-cart-pages/

He mentions the same filter as @Ewout above,

> ```
> add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
>
> function redirect_to_checkout() {
>     global $woocommerce;
>     $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
>     return $checkout_url;
> ```
>
> }

but one line of code stands out and is of super value for me for my current woocommerce project:

There is a direct link that a user can use to automatically bypass the product page.
http://your-site.com/?add-to-cart=37

'37' will be replaced by your product ID.

This was useful for me to eliminate unnecessary steps and take users directly to checkout from the home page and other non-woocommerce pages/posts.

Comment: `add_to_cart_redirect` is deprecated now, use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` instead.

Comment: get_checkout_url() is deprecated as of 2.5.0 in favor to wc_get_checkout_url()

Answer (score 1):

Filter *add_to_cart_redirect* is deprecated in WooCommerce 2.6. Use *woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect* instead.

Add this to your functions.php :

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function() {
  return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
} );
```

Comment: HI @Christian Lescuyer this function works fine, however I would like to know how do I add an additional "Checkout" button next to "Add to cart" and assign it on that button but not globally on ALL "add to cart" buttons throughout the site..any idea?

Comment: @gil-hamer You will have to modify the theme. Locate the “Add to cart” button on the page you want, and add your own button. This is not so simple, because you must not modify the main theme (your modifications will be overwritten at the next upgrade). The usual way is to add a child theme. If you already have one, no problem!

Comment: Thanks @Christian Lescuyer

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in the themes function.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_skip_cart_redirect_checkout' );
 
function woo_skip_cart_redirect_checkout( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On shop page, if you want use ajax and redirect toghether. The second method only when there are some condition, you can use this filter and leave on Woocommerce setting ajax enabled:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', array( $this, 'add_quantity_input' ), 4, 2);
```

to remove on a class attribute `ajax_add_to_cart` and change the href value to checkout url page;

On my template case:

```
public function add_quantity_input($text = null, $product = null) {
    global $product, $woocommerce;

    if ( $text != null and $product != null  ) {
        if(ismycondition($product->id)) {
            $s = explode('class="', $text);
            $s[2]=str_replace('ajax_add_to_cart', '', $s[2]);
            $text = implode('class="', $s);

            $text = preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="'.$woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url().'"$3>', $text);
        }
    }

    return $text;
}
```

I hope that this help.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions actually worked out for me, the filter add_to_cart_redirect was triggering on every page,not only on the cart.I did some modification on the suggested answer.

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
  function redirect_to_checkout() {
  if(is_cart()){
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
  ?>
  <script>
  location = '<?=$checkout_url?>';
  </script>
  <?php 
  }
}
```