# Disabling cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I would like to disable the WooCommerce cart functionality by all means.

My shop has only a single product, so cart is doesn't really needed.

My desired flow is Click on buy button -> go to checkout page.

Incase user goes back and redo the same process, checkout page will not show 2 products in summary buy just 1.

Any tips on how to achieve this smoothly ?

Thanks,

Comment: @Dave Thanks, but I would like to use woocommerce default checkout page that contains payment method, shipping info etc..

Answer (score 4):

**You will Need 4 code snippets:**

1) Disabling quantities buttons (on product page):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );
```

2) Add-to-cart validation, **allowing just one product in cart**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_product_is_in_cart' );
function check_product_is_in_cart() {
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return true;
}
```

3) Checkout redirect customer when your product is added to cart *(with modern syntax)*:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    // OR ALSO: 
    // return get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id'));
}
```

The code comme from this answer (with the correct new syntax): [Woocommerce add to cart button redirect to checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592633/woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-redirect-to-checkout/15597933#15597933)

4) Redirect Cart page to Checkout page (in case of):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout');
function skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout() {
    if(is_cart()){
        wp_redirect(WC()->cart->get_checkout_url());
        // OR ALSO:
        // wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ) );

        exit; // This is mandatory with wp_redirect()
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.

---

**Disabling redirect to Cart on `add-to-cart` action and Ajax add-to-cart on Shop page and archives pages *(optional)***

> You can also disable some settings in WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display *(tab)*.

Optionally keep that 2 options disabled *(and save settings)*:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to skip the cart page the easiest way it is to go to the **Woocommerce->Settings->Checkout and set Cart Page to "Checkout" page**

Or use this snippet

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
 global $woocommerce;
 $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
 return $checkout_url;
}
```

**Don't forget to disable Ajax Add to cart and  Redirect to the cart page after successful addition in Woocommerce->Settings->Products->Display**
If you use the first method you can check the Redirect to the cart page after successful addition.

For the limit one item in checkout use this snippet.
In this way, the customer only can buy one item, if the customer goes to another product and tries to buy it, the cart will be cleaned and the last item added.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );
function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```